# X writing top of screen to random parts of framebuffer - Xorg problem?

Tags: debian, xorg, graphics, framebuffer

I have an ASUS laptop with an SIS graphics card.  The default Xorg generated when I installed Debian (well, technically Raspbian Desktop) was at 640x480, yet it can easily do better as it's a 1280x800 screen and Xvesa on TinyCore was able to do 1024x768x24 with it fine. Therefore, I started adjusting.  First I tried the closest thing to a proper driver for it (found on Github) but I was unable to get that to work even once compiled.  However, since I knew that it *should* work with VESA (since Xvesa was fine with it), I set the screen driver to "vesa", started with a generated Xorg and worked with it from there, on and off, for about a year.  It is now to the point where it *almost* works, but the issue is a strange one: the top few pixels of the screen are black where they should be and instead are written elsewhere.  On loading X they are written at the bottom, so to begin with I presumed some offsetting issue, but when you move the mouse, the screen refreshes and this section is redrawn elsewhere, in seemingly random parts of the screenbuffer (and scrubbed from prior locations when any update occurs nearby).  I presume that there is something I can do in Xorg to fix this but I can't figure out what.

My current Xorg is as follows (commented out lines are preserved as evidence of what I've tried in the past):

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
        Load "dri"
#       Load "v4l"
        Load "extmod"
        Load "type1"
        Load "freetype"
        Load "glx"
        Load "GLcore"
        Load "i2c"
        Load "bitmap"
        Load "ddc"
        Load "int10"
        Load "vbe"
        Load "speedo"
        Load "record"
#       Load "dri2"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "Monitor0"
    Vendorname  "Generic LCD Display"
    Modelname   "LCD Panel 1280x800"
#   Horizsync   20 - 107
#   Vertrefresh 50 - 185
#   Horizsync   31.5 - 50.0
#   Vertrefresh 56.0 - 65.0
    Horizsync   31.5 - 48.0
#   Vertrefresh 50.0 - 70.0
    Vertrefresh 56.0 - 60.0
#   modeline    "640x480@60" 25.2 640 656 752 800 480 490 492 525 -vsync -hsync
#   modeline    "800x600@60" 40.0 800 840 968 1056 600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync
#   modeline    "1024x768@60" 74.48 1280 1336 1472 1664 720 721 724 746 -Hsync +Vsync
    modeline    "640x480@60.00" 23.75  640 664 720 800  480 483 487 500 -Hsync +Vsync
    modeline    "800x600@60.00" 38.25  800 832 912 1024  600 603 607 624 -Hsync +Vsync
    modeline    "1024x768@60" 63.50  1024 1072 1176 1328  768 771 775 798 -Hsync +Vsync
    modeline    "1280x768@60" 79.50  1280 1344 1472 1664  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
    modeline    "1280x800@60" 83.46 1280 1344 1480 1680 800 801 804 828 -hsync +vsync
    Gamma       1.0
EndSection

Section "Server Flags"
        Option "IgnoreABI"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Card0"
    VendorName  "Silicon Integrated Systems [SiS]"
    BoardName   "771/671 PCIE VGA Display Adapter"
    Busid   "PCI:1:0:0"
    Driver  "vesa"
    Screen 0
    Option   "DPMS"
        Option   "ShadowFB"
        Option   "MaxXFBMem"
##  Option   "AccelMethod"       "uxa"
    Option   "AccelMethod"       "EXA"
#   Option   "AccelMethod"       "XAA"
##        VideoRam           524032
        VideoRam             262016
    Option   "PreferredMode"         "1024x768"
    Option   "EnableSiSCtrl"         "true"
    Option   "UseFBDev"          "true"
    Option   "DRI"           "true"
    Option   "TurboQueue"            "true"
    Option   "FastVram"              "true"
    Option   "UseSSE"                "true"
#   Option   "UseTiming1280"         "true"
    Option   "RenderAccel"           "true"
    Option   "XAANoOffscreenPixmaps" "true"
    Option   "AllowGLXWithComposite" "true"
#   Option   "AddARGBGLXVisuals"     "true"
    Option   "backingstore"          "true"
#   Option   "TearFree"              "true"
#   Option   "TripleBuffer"          "true"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier    "Screen0"
        Monitor       "Card0"
        Device        "Monitor0"
        Defaultdepth  24
        SubSection "Display"
        Viewport  0 0
            Depth     1
        Virtual   1024 768
#       Virtual   1280 800
            Modes     "1280x800@60"    "1280x768@60"    "1024x768@60"    "800x600@60"    "640x480@60"
#            Modes     "1280x800@60"    "1024x768@60"    "800x600@60"    "640x480@60"
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
        Viewport  0 0
            Depth     4
        Virtual   1024 768
#       Virtual   1280 800
            Modes     "1280x800@60"    "1280x768@60"    "1024x768@60"    "800x600@60"    "640x480@60"
#            Modes     "1280x800@60"    "1024x768@60"    "800x600@60"    "640x480@60"
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
        Viewport  0 0
            Depth     8
        Virtual   1024 768
#       Virtual   1280 800
            Modes     "1280x800@60"    "1280x768@60"    "1024x768@60"    "800x600@60"    "640x480@60"
#            Modes     "1280x800@60"    "1024x768@60"    "800x600@60"    "640x480@60"
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
        Viewport  0 0
            Depth     15
        Virtual   1024 768
#       Virtual   1280 800
            Modes     "1280x800@60"    "1280x768@60"    "1024x768@60"    "800x600@60"    "640x480@60"
#            Modes     "1280x800@60"    "1024x768@60"    "800x600@60"    "640x480@60"
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
        Viewport  0 0
            Depth     16
        Virtual   1024 768
#       Virtual   1280 800
            Modes     "1280x800@60"    "1280x768@60"    "1024x768@60"    "800x600@60"    "640x480@60"
#        Modes     "1280x800@60"    "1024x768@60"    "800x600@60"    "640x480@60"
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
        Viewport  0 0
            Depth     24
#       Virtual   1280 768
        Virtual   1024 768
#       Virtual   1280 800
        Modes     "1280x800@60"    "1280x768@60"    "1024x768@60"    "800x600@60"    "640x480@60"
        EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "DRI"
    Mode         0666
EndSection
# 1024x768 59.92 Hz (CVT 0.79M3) hsync: 47.82 kHz; pclk: 63.50 MHz
# 640x480 59.38 Hz (CVT 0.31M3) hsync: 29.69 kHz; pclk: 23.75 MHz
# 800x600 59.86 Hz (CVT 0.48M3) hsync: 37.35 kHz; pclk: 38.25 MHz
# 1280x768 59.87 Hz (CVT) hsync: 47.78 kHz; pclk: 79.50 MHz
```

Screen just after load

[image: Screen just after load]

Screen Later

[image: Screen Later]

Screen on Menu

[image: Screen on Menu]

Screen on shutdown

[image: Screen on shutdown]

Comment: Probably related: [askubuntu.com/questions/952001](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952001)